# What does "parity pattern" mean?

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, pigeonhole-principle

> Five lattice points are chosen in the plane lattice. Prove that you can always choose two of these points such that the segment joining these points pass through another lattice point. (The lattice consists of all points of the plane with integral coordinates).

The solution reads as follows;

> Let us consider the **parity pattern** of the coordinates of these lattice points. There are only four possible patterns: $(e,e) , (e,o) , (o,e) , (o,o)$. Among the five lattice points, there will be two points, say $a= (a, b)$ and $B = (c,d)$ with the same parity pattern. Consider the midpoint $L$ of $AB$.  $L= ( \frac{a+c}{2} , \frac{b+d}{2} )$.  $a$ and $c$ as well as $b$ and $d$ have the **same parity**, and so $L$ is a lattice point.

I do not fully understand the solution provided.
How did the midpoint idea come from?
How does it work?
Would appreciate any insight provided by anyone to this solution.

Comment: Parity refers to "Even" or "odd".  Here, there are four possible states for a point in the integer lattice:  $(1,1)$ is (odd, odd), $(0,0)$ is (even, even) and so on.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now it does make more sense. But the latter parts?

Comment: EVerything else is clear, isn't it?  Just work it with examples.  Say your points are $(0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (1,0), (2,5)$.  Go through the program to find the two points on that list whose midpoint is also a lattice point.

Comment: Ok I get it now

Comment: As for explaining why there must be at least two who have the same parity pattern, this follows from the [pigeon-hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), loosely stated as "if you have $n$ objects, each of whom are described by one of $m$ categories with $n>m$, then there must necessarily be some category with at least two objects described by it" or more flavorful, "if you put $n$ pigeons into $m$ holes with $n>m$ then there must be some hole with at least two pigeons in it."

Comment: I’d say the midpoint idea does require some insight.  Two distinct lattice points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ have a lattice point between them if and only if $x_2-x_1$ and $y_2-y_1$ have a common factor.  The intuition here is that the common factor is most likely to be $2$, and that the statement still holds if we assume it must be $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abababababab
cdcdcdcdcdcd
abababababab
cdcdcdcdcdcd
abababababab
cdcdcdcdcdcd
abababababab
cdcdcdcdcdcd
abababababab
cdcdcdcdcdcd
abababababab
cdcdcdcdcdcd
```

If you pick any five points, two of them must be the same letter. The midpoint of any two same letters is another letter.

Answer (score 2):

It means whether the coordinates of the point are "both even", "first even second odd", "first odd and second even" or "both odd". I think the "zeros" are actually o's?
The midpoint idea, well I don't know how to come up with it, but it works, since then the sum of coordinates will always be even and you can divide by 2 to get another lattice point.

Comment: You are right. Have edited the question.